# Pass data to another screen when Gridview item is clicked

Tags: dart, flutter

I am a Java developer learning flutter. I need to pass data to another screen when an item of a Gridview has been clicked. I tried several online helps and could not find a better solution,

my class is,

```
class Product extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ProductState();
  }
}

var productList = [
  {
    "name": "Product 1",
    "image": "assets/products/product1.jpg",
    "price": 6.99,
    "description": "30% off",
  },
  .
  .
  .
  .
];

class _ProductState extends State<Product> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: productList.length,
      gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return FeatureProduct(
          productName: productList[index]['name'],
          productImage: productList[index]['image'],
          productPrice: productList[index]['price'],
          productDescription: productList[index]['description'],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class FeatureProduct extends StatelessWidget {
  final String productImage;
  final String productName;
  final String productDescription;
  final double productPrice;

  FeatureProduct(
      {this.productImage,
      this.productName,
      this.productPrice,
      this.productDescription});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Hero(
        tag: productName,
        child: Material(
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              // print(productName);
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => new ProductDetail(
                        product: FeatureProduct(
                          productName: productName,
                          productImage: productImage,
                          productDescription: productDescription,
                          productPrice: productPrice,
                        ),
                      ),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: GridTile(
                footer: Container(
                  color: Colors.white70,
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Text(
                      productName,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      "RM $productPrice",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      productDescription,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    productImage,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProductDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  final FeatureProduct product;

  ProductDetail({this.product});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("${product.productName}"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Text('${product.productDescription}'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried but getting following exception during the execution of above code,

> I/flutter ( 7767): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SCHEDULER LIBRARY
>   ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>       I/flutter ( 7767): The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
>       I/flutter ( 7767): There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
>       I/flutter ( 7767): Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (typically a PageRoute subtree), each Hero
>       I/flutter ( 7767): must have a unique non-null tag.
>       I/flutter ( 7767): In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: Product 5
>       I/flutter ( 7767): Here is the subtree for one of the offending heroes:
>       I/flutter ( 7767): # Hero(tag: Product 5, state: _HeroState#c56bf)
>       I/flutter ( 7767): # └KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#ef976]
>       I/flutter ( 7767): #  └Material(type: canvas, state: _MaterialState#d2e02)
>       I/flutter ( 7767): #   └AnimatedPhysicalModel(duration: 200ms, shape: rectangle, borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero, elevation: 0.0,
>   color: Color(0xfffafafa), animateColor: false, shadowColor:
>   Color(0xff000000), animateShadowColor: true, state:
>   _AnimatedPhysicalModelState#8cf00(ticker inactive))

How could I fix this issue, please help me.

Comment: is productName Unique for Each product in the List ?

Comment: in your error it clearly stated - In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: Product 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Order to fix the Stated Error you need to have Unique tag assigned to `hero` Widget.

I would Suggest to use the `index` Value instead of `productName`.

Updated Code would Look Like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Product extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ProductState();
  }
}

var productList = [
  {
    "name": "Product 1",
    "image": "assets/products/product1.jpg",
    "price": 6.99,
    "description": "30% off",
  },
  {
    "name": "Product 2",
    "image": "assets/products/product1.jpg",
    "price": 6.99,
    "description": "30% off",
  },
  {
    "name": "Product 3",
    "image": "assets/products/product1.jpg",
    "price": 6.99,
    "description": "30% off",
  },
  {
    "name": "Product 4",
    "image": "assets/products/product1.jpg",
    "price": 6.99,
    "description": "30% off",
  },
];

class _ProductState extends State<Product> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: productList.length,
      gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return FeatureProduct(
          productName: productList[index]['name'],
          productImage: productList[index]['image'],
          productPrice: productList[index]['price'],
          productDescription: productList[index]['description'],
          index: index,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class FeatureProduct extends StatelessWidget {
  final String productImage;
  final String productName;
  final String productDescription;
  final double productPrice;
  final int index;

  FeatureProduct(
      {this.productImage,
      this.productName,
      this.productPrice,
      this.index,
      this.productDescription});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Hero(
        tag: index,
        child: Material(
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              // print(productName);
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => new ProductDetail(
                        product: FeatureProduct(
                          productName: productName,
                          productImage: productImage,
                          productDescription: productDescription,
                          productPrice: productPrice,
                        ),
                      ),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: GridTile(
                footer: Container(
                  color: Colors.white70,
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Text(
                      productName,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      "RM $productPrice",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      productDescription,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    productImage,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProductDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  final FeatureProduct product;

  ProductDetail({this.product});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("${product.productName}"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Text('${product.productDescription}'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```